# What portion of impulse is received by the cylinder?

Tags: forces, pressure, ideal-gas

Condition:

A cylinder with a piston are situated along Y axis. 
Piston receives an impulse (P1) along Y axis and transmits it to the cylinder through a gas medium with which cylinder is filled. The impulse received by the cylinder along Y axis is P2.

Question:

Is P1 = P2?

Note: we are only considering the Y component of kinetic impulse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the gas will be compressed and it will exert the same pressure on *all walls*(not just along the y axis) of the cylinder. So force along y axis will be diminished. This example is somewhat similar to hydraulic(gas instead) shock absorbers.

Comment: OP is asking about impulse, not force at a given instant.

Comment: $Impulse=force\times time$